# post to iframe in another page

Tags: html, post, iframe

I am having a real struggle trying to accomplish something for work.

I have a starting page with a textbox and a button. I want to be able to post the value entered in the textbox to an iframe, but the iframe is on another another web page called iframeholder.

I am not allowed to session variables or querystring. It has to be post.

I want to send the value of TextBox_Link to the iframe and be able to store it as the value of a ListItem in the RadioButtonList. I greatly appreciate any feedback.

Starting Page

```
<body>  
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
<div>  
<table>  
<tr>  
<td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox_Link" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>  
</tr>  
<tr>  
<td><asp:Button ID="Button_Post" runat="server" Text="Button" /></td>  
</tr>  
</table>  
</div>  
</form>
```

iframeholder page

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<iframe src ="iframe.aspx" name="iframe" width="100%" height="300">
</div
</form>
</body>
```

iframe

```
<body>
       <form id="form1" runat="server">  
       <div>  
           <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server">  
               <asp:ListItem>Link1</asp:ListItem>  
           </asp:RadioButtonList>  
           <br />  
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Submit" />  
       </div>  
       </form>  
   </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `target='iframe'` in your `<form>` tag.